# Kivy android storage access permission denied

Tags: android, kivy, storage, android-permissions, buildozer

I'm trying to access storage of my Android device with Kivy.
In a previous app with kivy 2.0.0 and a Buildozer version < 1.5 (can't find which version I used) it worked well. But I can't do it again.

The path of the storage I'm trying to access is

```
/storage/emulated/0/
```

using the `primary_external_storage_path()` method from `android.storage` library.

I try to create a folder called `TestKivy` with the function `os.mkdir(os.path.join(self.primary_ext_storage, "TestKivy"))`.

When the app launches for the first time, it asks me if I authorize storage access and I say yes.

The app is running well but when I click the button, it crashs with this error :

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/storage/emulated/0/TestKivy'
```

I also tried accessing public folders like "Downloads" with `os.mkdir(os.path.join(self.primary_ext_storage, "Downloads", "TestKivy"))` but same error.

Here are my parameters :

Android device : Xiaomi Mi 9T

MIUI version : MIUI Global 12.0.5 Stable 12.0.5.0(QFJEUXM)

Android version : 10 QKQ1.190825.002

Buildozer 1.5.0

Buildozer.spec (all the other parameters are commented with #):

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = My Application

# (str) Package name
package.name = myapp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy

# (list) Supported orientations
# Valid options are: landscape, portrait, portrait-reverse or landscape-reverse
orientation = portrait

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (list) Permissions
# (See https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/buildoptions/#build-options-1 for all the supported syntaxes and properties)
android.permissions = android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

# (list) The Android archs to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
# In past, was `android.arch` as we weren't supporting builds for multiple archs at the same time.
android.archs = arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a

# (bool) enables Android auto backup feature (Android API >=23)
android.allow_backup = True

#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.10.0

# (bool) Whether or not to sign the code
ios.codesign.allowed = false

[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1
```

Here is the python code of my main.py file :

```
import os
from kivy.utils import platform


# Import kivy modules
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

# Create app
class HelloApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.btn = Button(text="Hello World")
        self.btn.bind(on_press=self.on_press_button)
        return self.btn
    
    def on_start(self):
        if platform == "android":

            # Import necessary modules for Android permissions
            from android.storage import primary_external_storage_path
            from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission

            # Request storage access permissions
            request_permissions([
                Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            ])

        # Set the default storage path depending on the device
        self.primary_ext_storage = primary_external_storage_path() if platform == "android" else os.environ["HOME"]


    def on_press_button(self, instance):
        # Create folder in the default storage path
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(self.primary_ext_storage, "TestKivy"))
    
# Run app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    HelloApp().run()
```

Comment: You should have started your post telling exact full path of the used file. Not afterwards. And you should have told us who put that file there. At the beginning. And you should have told us if you tried to read a file or create one. Please edit your post as we dont know what this is about.

Comment: Hello @blackapps thank you for your comment. I edited your point 1 and 3 but I'm not sure what you are asking when you say "you should have told us who put that file there". Is it possible to explain your request please ?

Comment: So you ate trying to create a folder. Not a file. Not even that was clear. If you are only trying to create a folder than my question who put that file there is nonsense of course.

Comment: Do not blindly call mkdir(). Only call it when the folder does not exist yet. And check the return value

Comment: For Android 10 devices add request legacy external storage to application tag of manifest file.